# Outlook Add-in: Usernames not matching between Office.js and Rest API

Tags: office-js, outlook-restapi, outlook-web-addins

I'm a developer working on an add-in for Microsoft Outlook, and we've been encountering a login issue with some of our users.

In our code, one of the ways we validate users with our system is by comparing the email address retrieved from Office.js to the email address we have stored for them on the server.

We get the email address from Office.js using `Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress` and match it to the email address from the ‘me’ endpoint (`https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me`) but these two don't always return the same address.

It seems that the mismatch might have something to do with when the user has a new primary alias or has switched to a new domain.

I have a few questions:

- Is this the correct way to get the two email addresses?
- When a user changes domains or aliases, is the change propagated to the front-end Office.js and the backend endpoint in different ways, such as different cache layers?
- Is there another endpoint we can call to get the two addresses to always match?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A `user` can have more than one email address. By the default, the `/me` endpoint only returns the primary email address. The rest are held in the `proxyAddresses` property.

You can ask `/me` to return the additional properties by adding it to a `select` clause like this:

```
/me?$select=proxyAddresses,displayName,id,jobTitle,mail,userPrincipalName
```

Comment: Thank you for this information.  We are able to retrieve the proxy addresses using the Graph API, but not the Office365 REST API.  Our app is using Office365 REST API primarily, and we get a response of “Could not find a property named proxyAddresses on type Microsoft.OutlookServices.User”.  Is there a way we could fetch the proxy addresses using the Office365 REST API?

Comment: I would strongly consider using Microsoft Graph. At some point you will have to do this anyway, Graph is where all the APIs are migrating. Given that you're able to pull a token with scopes for both Outlook REST API and Microsoft Graph, there is little reason to not start using it today.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. We're looking into switching over to Microsoft Graph, but it looks like doing so might require us to ask our existing users for new permissions. Do you have any suggestions on what we could do if we have existing REST refresh tokens and want to use the Microsoft Graph API without prompting users for any additional permissions?

Our existing refresh tokens have these permissions scopes: ["openid", "email", "profile", "https://outlook.office.com/Mail.ReadWrite", "https://outlook.office.com/Mail.Send", "https://outlook.office.com/Calendars.ReadWrite", "offline_access"]

Comment: You cannot add scopes to a refresh_token. You'll need to push them back through the primary auth path in order to obtain updated consent before they'll show up.